# Is there an alternative to PyMedia

Tags: python, video, media

Is there an alternative to PyMedia to decode different video formats and be able to extract frames as images for further processing?

Currently I have to be able to do something like the following (not working code extract, just to give an idea):

```
demuxer = muxer.Demuxer(FORMAT)
streams = demuxer.parse(open(VIDEO).read(BUFFER_SIZE))
codec = vcodec.Decoder(CODEC)

for stream in streams:
    frame = codec.decode(stream[1])
    fdata = frame.convert(2)
    img = Image.fromstring("RGB", fdata.size, fdata.data)
    # ...further processing of image...
```

Comment: Any particular reason you need an alternative to PyMedia?

Comment: Because it is dead (last update to the CVS is around 2006) and does not build with a reasonable configuration on a vanilla debian install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try Pyffmpeg https://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/...

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out and if the case flag this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pyffmpeg seems to be lagging a few years behind most recent ffmpeg releases, so not sure whats the status there :S One possible solution could be [moviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/crash_course/crash_course.html), which is also ffmpeg based...
[According to this video intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBy0vfExhJ8) it may be promising